# Multiple typeform embeds on one page

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a page that is embedding 25 type forms (http://www.typeform.com).

Each time the type form is embedded I add a link and then the script below it (see below).

When the link is clicked, it opens a popup on the page with the form inside it.

I'm wondering, is it possible to add the script only once and then have each link trigger it when it is clicked, rather than add the script for every embed? I assume it weighs heavily on the page load having that script load 25 times.

```
<a class="typeform-share" href="https://TYPEFORMACCOUNTNAME.typeform.com/to/OnOMuV" data-mode="1" target="_blank">APPLY</a>

<script>(function(){var qs,js,q,s,d=document,gi=d.getElementById,ce=d.createElement,gt=d.getElementsByTagName,id='typef_orm',b='https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/share.typeform.com/';if(!gi.call(d,id)){js=ce.call(d,'script');js.id=id;js.src=b+'share.js';q=gt.call(d,'script')[0];q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q)}})()</script><p class="share-this-role">Share this role</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, and tested with some my typeform widgets, you should be safe with just last one `<script>...</script>` tag on your html, if it's contain the same `XXX.js` file, for example:

**Example 1**

there's a `share.js` in your code:

```
<script>(function(){var qs,js,q,s,d=document,gi=d.getElementById,ce=d.createElement,gt=d.getElementsByTagName,id='typef_orm',b='https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/share.typeform.com/';if(!gi.call(d,id)){js=ce.call(d,'script');js.id=id;js.src=b+'share.js';q=gt.call(d,'script')[0];q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q)}})()</script>
```

And remove other `<script>...</script>` if it contains `share.js` **except** last one;

**Example 2**

there's `widget.js` in below code:

```
<script>(function(){var qs,js,q,s,d=document,gi=d.getElementById,ce=d.createElement,gt=d.getElementsByTagName,id='typef_orm',b='https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/share.typeform.com/';if(!gi.call(d,id)){js=ce.call(d,'script');js.id=id;js.src=b+'widget.js';q=gt.call(d,'script')[0];q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q)}})()</script>
```

and it's safe to remove all other `<script>...</script>` which contains `widget.js` **except** last one;

*so it's based on JS files in the typeform code to work*

**Don't lost any `.js`, and you don't need more than 1**

Correct me if your test is not work. Since it's 25 forms it's not easy to predict all the things.